# Method parameter ordering

Tags: api-design, naming

Assume that I am implementing a method that takes a data source in a system. Assume that it's a multi-tenant system, so a data source belongs to an organization (as other relevant entities, like users/datasets/etc). There are two ways to go for it:

1. `getDataSource(dataSourceName, organizationId)`
2. `getDataSource(organizationId, dataSourceName)`

Which one is better, and why?

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways that parameter order is forced is that optional parameters always go last. So if in your case it's possible to omit a specific data source name (because you have a default name to fall back on), then `getDataSource(int organizationId, string dataSourceName = "default name")` is the appraoch you should take.

When not dealing with optional parameters (or if all parameters are optiona), on a technical level it doesn't really matter. This means that the answer is inherently subjective, as it hinges on personal preference. Additionally, the preferred order is contextual.

There are cases where the order of parameters stems from an inherently expected order to the data itself, for example `new DateTime(2020, 12, 31)`. yyyyMMdd is a well-accepted format (which avoids the ddMMyyyy versus MMddyyyy culture difference), and therefore the constructor parameters mimic the same expected order of year, month, day.
Similarly, if your culture has a preferred order to first name/last name of a person, you tend to see the same order in the first name/last name parameters of a method.

Developers tend to order parameters based on how central they are to the concept being discussed. For example, a person's name tends to go before a person's date of birth if we're passing a person's information to a method.
Why? Because people tend to think as the name as a more central piece of data than the date of birth. The identifies the person more, so it's considered to be more important. This is also why unique IDs tend to be the first parameter when they are among the parameters, as it's the best identifier there is.

The idea behind it all is **readability**. If people already expect data to be in a certain order, complying with that order makes the method calls easier to read (and remember).

Comment: It also depends on language. If you use a programming language that supports partial application and currying, that will definitely affect which order you place parameters.